# Why do they always say: "this is not financial advice"?

Tags: finance, prediction

Every single time there is a video about finance (especially Bitcoin), they always nag on about how:

> This is not financial advice.

And then they give financial advice.

Why do they have to say this? It really pisses me off. It's **obviously** financial advice, so why claim the opposite? Idiotic.

If this is some way to "protect themselves legally", that implies that you can be sued for not accurately predicting the future. That makes no sense. If that's the case, then any video about anything would have to give disclaimers to not repeat what they do in the video and whatnot.

It makes me very annoyed to hear and read this BS all the time, and it makes it impossible to take anything they say seriously. Nobody in their right mind holds them actually accountable after losing money following their financial advice. It's just *advice*. Not magical, 100% correct predictions about the future.

Comment: Questions about personal finance are off topic on this site (see our help center for more details)